# how to add keyboard event to text box when text box is read only in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have made on textbox which is readonly. I want that when user press a number from keyboard then they are entered in textbox. I have applied `onkeyup()` event in the text box but it is not working.

```
<input type="text" id="screen" value="0" onkeyUp="myFunction(event)" readonly=true; >
```

```
function myFunction(event){
    if ( event.keycode >= 48 && event.keycode <=57 ) {
        //some code here
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe better with `<input type="number">` or `<input pattern="\d+">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's keyCode and not keycode, and you can go with something like

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <=57 ) {
            document.getElementById("screen").value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        }
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/npCBs/

Do note that only the upper number keys will work, and not the num pad.

Comment: Listen to keyCodes between 96 to 105, if clicked, substract 48 from the keyCode and then get the result by String.fromCharCode

Comment: which event(keyup,keydown,keypress) should i use so that it works fine on all browser?

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` attribute specifically means that no input is to be accepted by the input that has the readonly attribute.

try adding the onkeyup attribute to body. the tradeoff is that any keyboard event will be captured

```
<body onkeyUp="myFunction(event)">
...
 <input type="text" id="screen" value="0"  readonly=true; >            
...
</body>
```

this should call the `myFunction` everytime user presses a key.